# Does the notion of graphs with vertex multiplicity exist?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, definitions

I need to use graphs where each vertex gets a natural number, $b(v)$, its multiplicity. These numbers indicate how many 'replications' of the vertex we have.

It is actually a way to write in a compact way a graph which has a lot of twin vertices: two vertices $u$ and $v$ are twin if $N(u)=N(v)$ (they are not adjacent).

Since the twin relation is an equivalence relation, there is a unique way to write any graph in a reduced form as a graph with vertex multiplicities.

Here is an example:
[image: Here is an example of the reduction]

This representation is particularly useful when vertices represent some items with large quantity.

Does someone know if such a concept already exists ? What's the usual name ? Do you have some references ?

Comment: A similar but not identical equivalence relation was defined by Servatius in his study of graph groups (aka right-angled Artin groups).  Write $u\geq v$ if $N(v)\subseteq N(u)\cup\{u\}$ and $u\sim v$ if $u\geq v$ and $v\geq u$.  In other words, $u$ and $v$ are also allowed to be adjacent.

Comment: Indeed, the equivalence classes with this relation will be either clique or stable sets. Do you know if anyone else use this relation and the reduced graph behind ?

Comment: It's heavily used in subsequent work on outer automorphisms of graph groups.  Look at the citations of Servatius' paper.  The reference is: H. Servatius, Automorphisms of graph groups,
*J. Algebra* 126 (1989), no. 1, 34–60.

Comment: A similar construction has been called binary relation orbifold (Borchmann, Daniel: _Context Orbifolds_, Diploma Thesis, TU Dresden, 2009, [link](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/~borch/forschung/)).

Comment: This is also a special case of the "generalized lexicographic product of graphs", also known as "local join" or "composition" $G[H_1,H_2,\dots,H_n]$ where the $H_i$ consist of isolated vertices only.  See eg. Sabidussi, "Graph derivatives" or item 16 of Section 2.7 in Cvetkovic, Doob, Sachs, "Spectra of Graphs".

Comment: The link to Borchmann's diploma thesis in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142467/does-the-notion-of-graphs-with-vertex-multiplicity-exist#comment367658_142467) above is broken, but it can be found now at https://iccl.inf.tu-dresden.de/w/images/8/81/Orbifolds.pdf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5699), they call these objects "blow-up graphs", since the operation of adding twins to a vertex is commonly called a blow-up. Putting integer weights on the vertices of a graph to signify by how much to blow up a vertex like you do above is fairly common.

Answer (score 4):

This notion is complementary to the notion of *vertex multiplication*, in which every vertex is replaced with a *homogeneous clique*.  This goes back to Lovasz' proof of the Weak Perfect Graph Theorem, and probably even earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard this concept called, logically enough, "vertex multiplication."  The first hit I got when I searched was [Small Survey on Perfect Graphs](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/eric.thierry/Graphes2010/michele-alberti.pdf) by Michele Alberti.  Be aware, though, that I've also heard the term "vertex multiplication" used when the multiple copies of a vertex form a clique rather than an independent set.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the use of this by Lovász for perfect graphs (mentioned by earlier answers), this has been used by Häggkvist to find high-degree four-chromatic triangle-free graphs. See

Häggkvist, R. (1981), "Odd cycles of specified length in nonbipartite graphs", Graph Theory (Cambridge, 1981), pp. 89–99, [MR0671908](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0069494).

Answer (score 1):

1. You might want to look up [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379510004775) where reduced graphs are studied, in the sense of Servatius (or very similar to it), from the viewpoint of spectral graph theory.
2. People have studied twin-free graphs quite a lot. One possible pointer is [this](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/EMIS/journals/EJC/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v14i1r16/pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence relation that HJRW defines in the comments (that is twin vertices may be adjacent) is related to the [cochromatic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoloring) $z(G)$ of a graph $G$.  The cochromatic number of $G$ is the minimum number of colours needed to colour $V(G)$ such that each colour class induces a clique or stable set.  Thus, the number of such equivalence classes gives an upper bound on the cochromatic number.

Comment: I agree but it does not really help with my question : with my relation it already gives an upperbound on the chromatic number, but it could be very bad !

Comment: I agree.  In general, I try to be pretty liberal with my answers to reference requests, since usually it is unclear what the OP is exactly looking for.  Ergo, it is possible that some semi-related concept may be helpful.  Sorry if it was not in this case. =)

Comment: Yes it is always good to know it :)

Answer (score 0):

A graph in which no two vertices have the same neighborhood is called a *point-determining graph* or *mating graph* or *mating-type graph*. See  [A006024](https://oeis.org/A006024) for references.

Comment: Thanks for the name and the reference. I can indeed assume that my graph is point-determining. But what about adding multiplicities on the vertices ? Do you know if something similar exists ?

Comment: I don't know anything about this.