# Name for a chain-like graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for graphs of the following type?

[image]

Namely, it has an integer function $\ell$ on the set of the vertex set such that
$v$ is adjacent to $w$ if and only if $$|\ell(v)-\ell(w)|\le 1.$$

**Postscript.** Maybe I can call it **multipath**?  It is a path with *multiplied vertices* as described in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/143705/).

Comment: Equivalently: start from a disjoint union of path graphs and replace any of the vertices by cliques.

Comment: @SamHopkins exactly

Comment: Related MO question: [Does the notion of graphs with vertex multiplicity exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/142467)

Comment: "lexicographic product"

Comment: @MartinRubey What exactly is your suggestion? This doesn't seem to be a graph product in any straightforward sense. If $G$ has $m$ vertices and $H$ has $n$ vertices then all the graph products of $G$ and $H$ that I'm aware of have $mn$ vertices, which is not the case here.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion of "multipath," if I heard that term without any definition and had to guess what it meant, I would guess that it would be a path with possibly repeated *edges* rather than a path whose *vertices* had multiplicity.

Comment: @TimothyChow: it is, more precisely (and trivially), the so called lexicographic product or local join $P_n[K_{i_1}, \dots, K_{i_n}]$.  See eg. Sabidussi, "Graph derivatives" or item 16 of Section 2.7 in Cvetkovic, Doob, Sachs, "Spectra of Graphs".   In particular, 2.7.16 of the latter exhibits the eigenvalues of $G[H_1,\dots,H_n]$, provided that the $H_i$ are regular.  In the case at hand, we should get $-1$ with multiplicity $\sum n_i - n$ together with the eigenvalues of the matrix $(a_{i, j} n_j + \delta_{i, j} (n_j - 1))$, where $(a_{i,j})$ is the adjacency matrix of the path.