# Did these graphs pop up somewhere?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

> Please let me know if the following graphs popped up in some problems.

Each of these graphs is described by 5 integers $n_1\geqslant k_1$, $n_2\geqslant k_2$, $l\geqslant 0$.
We take two complete graphs $K_{n_1}$ and $K_{n_2}$ and a path $P_l$ of length $l$,
the left endvertex of $P_l$ is connected to $k_1$ vertices of $K_{n_1}$ and
and the right endvertex of $P_l$ is connected to $k_2$ vertices of $K_{n_2}$.
In addition we assume that if $n_i>0$ then $k_i>0$, so the obtained graph is connected.

Here three examples for

- $n_1=4,k_1=2,l=3,k_2=2,n_2=4$;
- $n_1=4,k_1=2,l=0,k_2=0,n_2=0$;
- $n_1=2,k_1=2,l=0,k_2=2,n_2=2$.

[image]

These graphs encode solutions of [certain problem in metric geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.08016) related to the so-called graph comparison.

Comment: Might also be worth linking to your previous question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436027/name-for-a-chain-like-graph